# Zombie.js Returns Improper Page Content

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, zombie.js

I am new to zombie and just trying to get a basic test running. I have the following code:

```
var Browser = require('zombie');

var startTime = +new Date();

Browser.visit("http://zombie.labnotes.org/", function(e, browser) {
    var duration;

    console.log("Successfully visted the page");
    console.log(browser.html());

    duration = (+(new Date())) - startTime;
    console.log("Finished in (milliseconds): " + duration);
});
```

For some reason all I get back in the console is:

Successfully visted the page

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
Finished in (milliseconds): 5020
```

This is obviously not the right mark up and it takes quite a bit of time (5 seconds) to do that. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** ended up switching to a simpler model using request and jsdom. Here is the code I used:
    var request = require('request'),
        jsdom = require('jsdom');

```
//Tell the request that we want to fetch youtube.com, send the results to a callback function
request({uri: 'http://youtube.com'}, function(err, response, body){
    var self = this;
    self.items = [];

    //Just a basic error check
    if(err && response.statusCode !== 200){console.log('Request error.');}

    //Send the body param as the HTML code we will parse in jsdom
    //also tell jsdom to attach jQuery in the scripts and loaded from jQuery.com
    jsdom.env({
        html: body,
        scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js']
    }, function(err, window){
        //Use jQuery just as in a regular HTML page
        var $ = window.jQuery;

        console.log(body);
    });
});
```

Taken from: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/

But I would still like to know what went wrong with Zombie as I would like to use it for testing on other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work now that I upgraded to a new version of both Node.js and Zombie.js. Note that you cannot use a pre version of Node with zombie.js (one of the dependencies will fail saying that).

Use NVM to install the latest stable version (version 0.8.9 at time of writing).

Answer (score 2):

Browser is the class that is loaded through the require. You want to create a variable that is an instance of Browser and then call visit using that variable. Your code should be:

```
var Browser = require('zombie');

var startTime = +new Date();

my_browser = new Browser(); // Here's where you need to call new
my_browser.visit("http://zombie.labnotes.org/", function(e, browser) {
    var duration;

    console.log("Successfully visted the page");
    console.log(browser.html());

    duration = (+(new Date())) - startTime;
    console.log("Finished in (milliseconds): " + duration);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But no that's not it. I tried that. And you mean new Browser(). It's not ruby :). Also the visit method creates an instance and passes it back to the callback so that is not the issue. I think It might have been the install on Ubuntu.